# Trigger alert to Asp.net MVC application when record is inserted in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, firebase, push-notification, polling

I have scenario where i need to alert the web user when data inserted in db,

For this approach i used SignalR with Asp.net MVC which uses the polling but i need a concept like push notification (Firebase) rather than using a polling

What is the best approach to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

SignalR has multiple transport options longpolling and websockets. 
You can choose websockets if you don't want to use polling but it will support only HTML5 browsers.

Comment: Ok.. but how to get notification from database to Websocket whenever a data is inserted in db by any background service